# Why does Nginx keep redirecting me to localhost?

Tags: django, redirect, nginx, localhost, gunicorn

Using Django on the backend with Gunicorn, each time I submit a form and am supposed to be sent to `example.com/pagetwo` I am sent to `localhost/pagetwo` instead.

I'm new to Nginx so if someone could point out what the problem is I'd be most greatful :)

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location /static/ {
        root /srv;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/srv/sockets/website.sock;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Here is a form from the index page:

```
<form id='formone' method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is the action on your form correct?

Comment: I have added the form tag from the main page for reference

Comment: I assume you can get to example.com/pagetwo with a get request? Are you modifying your hosts file?

Comment: You did assume correctly but it looks like GwynBleidD narrowly beat you to answer. Thank you for the assistance though :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this situation, django is listening on some unix socket and all requests sent to django by nginx are local, so host that django sees is 'localhost'.

Django must build full URL for any redirection when you're submitting form. Because only domain django knows about is 'localhost', django will build URL using that host.

Nginx is used as gateway between django and clients, so it is responsible for changing all redirect urls sent by django to match domain name that nginx is serving site on. But line:

```
        proxy_redirect off;
```

is telling nginx "don't do that, don't rewrite that redirect URLs". That is causing redirection problem.

What you can do is: remove that line or change nginx configuration in way that it will properly inform django about domain name. To do that, you should add line:

```
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

With that line in config, nginx will pass real domain name to django instead of passing localhost. This is recommended way, because with that line nginx will be more transparent to django. There are also other header configuration lines that you should add here, so other things in django can work properly. For list of all configuration refer to documentation of wsgi server that you are using, for gunicorn it will be [here](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html).

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem :)
I will just note that in this case the `proxy_redirect off;` line was added after I first googled the problem which was still there without it. Adding `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` was the solution. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, my bad. Removing `proxy_redirect off;` will only help if you're not using unix socket, on unix sockets it won't change a thing. About not getting client IP address, you must add to your nginx config: `            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`.

Comment: Thank you again, I found the IP config in the nginx doc link you gave in the answer. Kudos good sir :)

Comment: <3 to you, fellow anonymous of the interweb

Answer (score 2):

I used the combination of this which fixed the issue for me

```
location / {
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   server_name_in_redirect off;
   proxy_redirect off;
   rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ https://my-website-url$1/ permanent;   #This will add trailing / to the url which will solve the issue.
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, i'm using `proxy_pass http://localhost:port` at the end.